# How do I stop Sublime Text 2 from automatically compiling coffeescript on save?

Tags: coffeescript, sublimetext2

When I save coffeescript files in Sublime Text 2, it automatically compiles it to javascript and creates a new file in that directory. This is an undesired behavior. How do I stop this from happening? When I save in a different text editor (e.g.: nano), this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `"compileOnSave": false` to `Sublime Text 2 > Preferences > Package Settings > Better Coffeescript > Settings - Default`